# Broken link in the head of template

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-api

Here is my exact issue. In the head of my theme I have a this link:

This link is broken, and is causing my page to slow down on load times. How can I remove or correct this link?

[Chrome devTools Exact Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf2bk.jpg)

Comment: Edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste all of your code into the box.

Comment: What code are you talking about?

Comment: ALL of your html and css

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my problem. I have a link in the <head></head> of my theme that is broken. I'm using wordpress and I have no clue how to remove or change this link. From research, wp_head() is where all the links for the stylesheets are located, but I can't find how to change the link or even find where they are.

Comment: can you put a link to the site then?

Comment: Www.visionbeyondborders.org

Comment: Thanks, I'll check now. Is that a Greek organization? I thought I've heard of it when I was there.

Comment: example, in this line, and the others  <li id="menu-item-1528" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1528"><a href="http://www.visionbeyondborders.org/trips/">Trips</a></li>      do you have a page in trips/  folder?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: the link is pointing to a desination folder called trips, meaning something has to be in there for that code to work

Comment: I will double check asap, at work atm. Did you find where that Google font api is linked?

Comment: this line in the <head> section is where the fonts start   '<link rel='stylesheet' id='tp-open-sans-css'  href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800' type='text/css' media='all' />'

Comment: How do you access that file and change the link, because the comment below will work but I don't know how to change or delete the linked style sheets

Comment: I don;t use Wordpress but according to Google http://easywpguide.com/wordpress-manual/appearance/updating-the-menu/editing-an-existing-menu-item/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your google font link with `https` protocol

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: How do I replace that link?

Comment: I finally found the style referenced above in the functions.php file and changed it to the correct one.